# how generic type with a recursive type parameter along with the abstract self method allows method chaining to work properly?

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, builder

I am reading **Effective Java Edition 3**. in chapter 2 page 14, the author talks about the builder pattern and presents this code:

```
public abstract class Pizza {
    public enum Topping { HAM, MUSHROOM, ONION, PEPPER, SAUSAGE }
    final Set<Topping> toppings;
    abstract static class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> {
        EnumSet<Topping> toppings = EnumSet.noneOf(Topping.class);
        public T addTopping(Topping topping) {
            toppings.add(Objects.requireNonNull(topping));
            return self();
        }
        abstract Pizza build();
        // Subclasses must override this method to return "this"
        protected abstract T self();
    }
    Pizza(Builder<?> builder) {
        toppings = builder.toppings.clone(); // See Item 50
    }
}
```

an implementation of above abstract class:

```
public class NyPizza extends Pizza {
    public enum Size { SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE }
    private final Size size;
    public static class Builder extends Pizza.Builder<Builder> {
        private final Size size;
        public Builder(Size size) {
            this.size = Objects.requireNonNull(size);
        }
        @Override public NyPizza build() {
            return new NyPizza(this);
        }
        @Override protected Builder self() { return this; }
    }
    private NyPizza(Builder builder) {
        super(builder);
        size = builder.size;
    }
}
```

and we can use code like this:

```
NyPizza pizza = new NyPizza.Builder(SMALL)
.addTopping(SAUSAGE).addTopping(ONION).build();
```

quote from the book:

> Note that `Pizza.Builder` is a *generic type* with *recursive type
> parameter*. this, along with the abstract self method, allows method
> chaining to work properly in subclasses, without the need for casts.

now my question is what power/value `<T extends Builder<T>>` added to `Pizza` class and how it is different with `<T extends Builder>`?  if you are going to explain `<T extends Builder<T>>` to a five years old kid in simple English how would you explain it?

and I can't figure out the purpose of abstract self method in the super class?

---

**I add this part because of the comment section**

Imagine I have changed the above codes like this(it is not going to be the best example just for illustration purposes):

I changed the `NyPizza.Builder` to be generic:

```
public class NyPizza extends Pizza {
    public enum Size { SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE }
    private final Size size;
    public static class Builder<T> extends Pizza.Builder<Builder<T>> {
        private final Size size;
        public Builder(Size size) {
            this.size = Objects.requireNonNull(size);
        }
        @Override public NyPizza build() {
            return new NyPizza(this);
        }
        @Override protected Builder self() { return this; }
    }
    private NyPizza(Builder builder) {
        super(builder);
        size = builder.size;
    }
}
```

and the `Pizza` class like this:

```
public abstract class Pizza {
    public enum Topping { HAM, MUSHROOM, ONION, PEPPER, SAUSAGE }
    final Set<Topping> toppings;
    abstract static class Builder<T extends Builder> {
        T obj;
        EnumSet<Topping> toppings = EnumSet.noneOf(Topping.class);
        public T addTopping(Topping topping) {
            toppings.add(Objects.requireNonNull(topping));
            return self();
        }

        public T builder(){
            return obj;
        }

        abstract Pizza build();
        // Subclasses must override this method to return "this"
        protected abstract T self();
    }
    Pizza(Builder<?> builder) {
        toppings = builder.toppings.clone(); // See Item 50
    }
}
```

and used the above classes like this:

`NyPizza.Builder<String> test = new NyPizza.Builder<String>(SMALL).builder();`

now because I didn't define `class Builder<T extends Builder>` in this form: `class Builder<T extends Builder<T>>` the `builder` method in the `Pizza` class should not be able to detect the type of the T is `NyPizza.Builder<String>` but it can. how is it possible? how change it to **need casting**?

Comment: Why is a 5 year-old kid using self-bounded generics? ;)

Comment: `self()` is used to avoid having to cast `this` to `T` (in `addTopping()`) - the cast would trigger a type safety warning

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine a class:

```
class Foo<T extends Foo<T>> {
  T foo() { ... }
}
```

What this is saying is that the `foo()` method, in the `Foo<T>` class, will return an instance of something that's also a `Foo<T>`, because all possible types represented by `T` are subclasses of `Foo<T>`.

So it *can* return itself - which is why it's useful for method chaining with builders; but there's actually nothing that stops it returning some other class within the bound.

If you were to declare it as:

```
class Foo<T extends Foo> {
  T foo() { ... }
}
```

then this makes `T` a *raw-typed* `Foo`: `foo()` returns a `Foo`, not a `Foo<T>`. Because raw types erase all generics, this means that in a call chain like `foo().foo()`, you are losing type information after the first call.

In many situations, this may not *feel* super-important. But [raw types should be avoided in pretty much all situations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). The consequences of a raw type here would be:

1. If you weren't returning the self type (alluded to above with the "there's actually nothing that stops it returning some other class"), you would lose that "other class" after the first method call.
2. If you had other generic methods in `Foo`, e.g. `List<String> myList() { ... }`, the raw-typed `Foo` would return raw `List`, not `List<String>` (raw types erase *all* generics, not just the ones related to the omitted type variables).

These clearly don't apply in all situations; but since it is simply bad practice to introduce unnecessary raw types, make sure you don't introduce them.

Comment: thank you. in "So it can return itself " and "but there's actually nothing that stops it returning some other class within the bound" when we didn't use `T extends Foo<T> ` and use only `T extends Foo` they have same effect?
I must confess I didn't figure out this part "all possible types represented by T are subclasses of Foo<T>" too :( can you please add more explanation?

Comment: `T extends Foo` means that methods returning `T` would be returning a `Foo`, which is a *raw type*, that is, you lose all the generic types.

Comment: thank you! I understand your point,  last question, in the effective java example if I use generics like `class Builder<T extends Builder>` then I can use method chaining without any casts. `NyPizza pizza = new NyPizza.Builder(SMALL)
.addTopping(SAUSAGE).addTopping(ONION).build();` how is it ok here?

Comment: Because `NyPizza.Builder` isn't a generic class: it has no type parameters. All the type parameters are specified in the `extends Pizza.Builder<Builder>`.

Comment: Or are you meaning why don't you need to cast to `NyPizza` at the end? Because the `build()` method has a covariant return type: `NyPizza` is a subclass of `Pizza`, so it's allowed to override `Pizza build()` with `NyPizza build()`.

Comment: your explanations totally make sense and I appreciate your time and effort you put into this. I edited the question and add some part that confused me! can you clarify  that ? thank you so much